# cv::cuda::FastFeatureDetector only accepts FastFeatureDetector::TYPE_9_16

Tags: opencv

Does anyone know why does `cv::cuda::FastFeatureDetector` only accepts `FastFeatureDetector::TYPE_9_16` as argument?

(there seems to be an assertion that fails if you use any other value for this parameter)

Comment: I was digging into about this. I have also seen your other post in github issues. I have lastly found that in [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/cudafeatures2d/src/fast.cpp). In this source file, it looks like they created if and only if detector type is `TYPE_9_16` . I couldnt find a reasonable reason why

Comment: I have found this because apparently `cv::cuda::FastFeatureDetector` does not find all keypoints in a image, and nobody seems to know why. I read calling with other argument might help but that seem not possible either.